# How to check ssh working between local Ubuntu and AWS instance Ubuntu

Tags: networking, ssh

I'm having problems making a `ssh` request from my local machine (Ubuntu) to an AWS instance (running Ubuntu).

Whilst I check all my AWS settings (Security Groups etc), what can I check on my local Ubuntu and the remote Ubuntu to help debug the problem?

It might be a problem with the AWS Ubuntu AMI, rather than the networking.

I ran:

```
sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN
```

on the remote machine and got:

```
systemd-r  432 systemd-resolve   14u  IPv4  15211      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.53:53 (LISTEN)
sshd       667            root    3u  IPv4  17141      0t0  TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
sshd       667            root    4u  IPv6  17152      0t0  TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
```

Comment: Well, you could *make* your local machine an SSH server, then try something like `ssh localhost`. What problems are you having, exactly?

Comment: @steeldriver Trying to ssh to an AWS Instance using a key but keep getting a timeout. I've got a real basic AWS setup (I havent changed any settings), followed the troubleshooting guide, so I want to check there isn't a problem on my side first.

Comment: @intrigued-66: Please [edit] your Question to add new information, properly formatted. Information added via comments is hard for you to format, hard for us to read and ignored by both current and future readers (who have better answers).  Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Help us help you.

Comment: @waltinator done

Comment: If you have a GitHub or GitLab account, you can try `ssh git@github.com`, `ssh git@gitlab.com`, etc. test if you can access public SSH servers. If you can, then the problem is mostly in the AWS configuration (which I think is more likely) - is your instance publicly accessible, does the SG allow external SSH access, etc.?

Comment: @muru turned out my default SecurityGroup didn't do what it claims. It's inbound rule was "allow everything" except it wasn't. I created a new SG, added rule for SSH and it worked. Weird.